# PDO Extract Data in While Loop

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to extract this data into a while loop and its literally returning nothing at all, any ideas whats wrong?

Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    require('include/db.php');
    require('include/init.php');
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
        $userid = $odb->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $result3 = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where ID = :id");
        $result3->bindValue(":id", $userid);
        $result3->execute();
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $username=$row['username'];
            $email=$row['email'];
            $rank=$row['rank'];
            $membership=$row['membership'];
            $expire=$row['expire'];
            $status=$row['status'];
            echo "
            Username: ".$username."<br />
            Email: ".$email."<br />
            Rank: ".$rank."<br />
            Membership: ".$membership."<br />
            Expire: ".$expire."<br />
            Status: ".$status."<br />
            ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You did not enter an ID!";
    }
?>
```

If you need any information let me know!

Comment: Can't have too many `isset` checks for `$_GET['id']` ;)

Comment: Also, what type of object is `$odb`? You shouldn't be escaping the id parameter and then binding it. Simply do the latter

Comment: Thats not the issue the $_GET['id'] works properly, I already tested that part.

Comment: $odb is a PDO object, I can show you the code for that.

Comment: In that case, `PDO` has no such method `real_escape_string` or `fetch_array`, nor should you use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. This code should not even execute

Comment: Ohk I see what you guys mean now, I was used to mysqli, can anyone actually write an answer explaining what to do?

Comment: This code would be throwing errors all over the place yet you've included none in your post. I suggest you enable proper error reporting (`display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in `php.ini`), set `PDO` to throw exceptions and consult the manual for the appropriate methods to use. You really only need to check out `PDOStatement::fetch`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using PDO, some functions have to be updated.  Instead of `mysql_escape_string()`, you can just prepare and bind the value and PDO will escape everything.  Also `fetch_array()` should be [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and `MYSQLI_ASSOC` should be [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.fetch-assoc).

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
if($id) {
    require('include/db.php');
    require('include/init.php');

    // Prepare && Binding will take care of escaping the string
    $result = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where ID = :id");
    $result->bindValue(":id", $id);

    $result->execute();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $rank = $row['rank'];
        $membership = $row['membership'];
        $expire = $row['expire'];
        $status = $row['status'];

        echo "
        Username: ".$username."<br />
        Email: ".$email."<br />
        Rank: ".$rank."<br />
        Membership: ".$membership."<br />
        Expire: ".$expire."<br />
        Status: ".$status."<br />
        ";
    }
} else {
    echo "You did not enter an ID!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again @Phil..sorry for all the initial errors, OP ;)

Comment: Im more confused now :$ What do I do? This doesn't exactly work.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get @user3023566

Comment: I turned on error reporting but that doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Returns this "array(1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" }"

Comment: @user3023566 check my updates to how `$_GET['id']` is handled, since it wasn't an integer the first conditional wouldn't pass.

Comment: @SamSullivan `is_numeric` returns `true` for numeric strings so `'20'` should be fine

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I guess I am waiting on a `var_dump($odb->errorInfo());` after `$result->execute();` before I can help anymore.

Comment: @SamSullivan I doubt you / OP will get anything from `errorInfo` unless the `users` table or `ID` column doesn't exist. It's more likely that there's simply no record for `ID = 20`

Comment: Sorry it took so long I will update with what that shows! @SamSullivan

Comment: It returns nothing to the page @SamSullivan